# Water, gas, electricity puzzle

Tags: discussion, duplicates

The question [Connect 3 houses with 3 wells](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17230/connect-3-houses-with-3-wells) is a duplicate of a question I'm almost certain we've already had on the site.  Searching for "gas is:question" or "connect is:question" or "overlap is:question" or "cross is:question" doesn't bring it up.

This isn't the first time I've seen duplicate puzzles on this site, but then have not been able to find the old one.  Typically these are common, well known puzzles, though, and I'm wondering if they are getting deleted.

Did I imagine the duplicate, or are these questions being deleted for one reason or another, or ???

Comment: Tagged `lateral-thinking` to encourage out of the box solutions... ;)

Comment: Sometimes the search doesn't work very well and miss questions for some reason. Try googling the contents of the question and add "puzzling" at the end, so for your question try searching "3 houses 3 wells puzzling" or "water gas electricity puzzling". All similar questions on the site will show up at the top.

Comment: @mmking Already done with several variations, ending with `site:puzzling.stackexchange.com` to ensure I get results only from here.  No luck - if a duplicate existed then it's most likely deleted now.  If not, then I'm imagining having seen it here.

Comment: If you can't find it on Google, it probably doesn't exist any more.